# CocosSharp and touches

Tags: android, ios, cocos2d-x, cocossharp

I have several sprites in a CocosSharp game, and for each of them I add a `CCEventListenerTouchAllAtOnce`.

I noticed that it doesn't matter where I touch, all of the sprites receive the `OnTouchesBegan/Moved/Ended` event.

Is there a way to make a sprite to react only to touches relevant to it?

Also, is there a built-in solution in CocosSharp  which handles overlapping sprites?
  (If the touch was  in an overlapping area, I'd like the top sprite to react to the touch, but not the bottom)

Answer (score 0):

Either write a hit text using the touch position and sprite bounding box, or consider using a MenuItemImage instead.

CCMenu.cs has an example implementation in it's ItemForTouch method.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to learn how to handle touch events, touch listeners, and swallowing touches.  When a sprite registers for touch events, any screen touch will fire the event.  It is then up to you to programmatically determine if the point touched is in the bounding box of the sprite.

[See this post for more detail.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33168953/android-game-drag-one-image-at-a-time-into-screen-from-a-group-of-images)